# Bash control+c process

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a couple of servers each that have a 'screen' that is running a program. This way, i am able to ssh in and monitor their out putat any given time.

The problem, is that i am often having to ssh in, log into the screen, control+c the process and then restart it.

I would like to write a bash script that would do this for each of my servers, and i think i understand how to do it, aside from the control+c bit.

```
ssh ubuntu@ipaddress
screen -dr that_one_screen
#control+c somehow
restart_process
```

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ctrl-C, just kill the process using "kill."

Follow-up (re: PID determination):

Generically, on Linux try something like:

```
ps -e | grep <your process name> | awk {'print $1'}
```

Start with "ps -e" to get the lay of the land and an idea of what you can filter on.

Comment: You'll have to know the process ID of the process you want to kill, of course. Should be easy with the right pgrep line...

Comment: Can @JonahBishop or conrad please explain how to obtain the PID so i can kill the process? say to start my process i say 'bundle exec rake start_that_one_process'

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on pgrep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) has some useful examples. Also see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep). I forgot about **pkill**, but it's also an option (see second link for more).

Comment: I don't use Ruby/rake, so I can't give specific advice.  You might be able to get your framework to give you the PID directly (Googling "bundle exec rake process id" gave some plausible results), but this is outside my expertise.

Adding generic comments as a follow-up to my answer...

Comment: Jonah's comment on pgrep is spot on and may well be better than mine... I'm so accustomed to grep/awk/sed that I sometimes overlook the more purpose-built utilities.

Comment: @ConradShultz pgrep ended up not working for me.. because it would only return the correct result if i fed in the name 'ruby' and i had multiple ruby processes on some servers. I would not have been able to solve the issue without your post. Thanks. :] (also, i thought i'd let you know i ended up having to do `ps aux -e` so i could get the actual name)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way I might implement a solution to this problem is the following:

On each system I wish to control, I would place a bash script that does two things: (1) kills the running process and (2) restarts it. I could then have a second bash script on my 'master' system that would simply call this script via an ssh command. Example:

**Script 1: recycle_process.sh** (placed on each system I wish to control)

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`pgrep 'my_process_name'`
kill $pid
# Launch 'my_process_name' (as a background process!)
```

**Script 2: do_recycle.sh** (placed on the master controller system)

```
#!/bin/bash
_host=$1
if(-z $_host) {
  echo "Gimme a host name to connect to!";
  exit(1);
}
ssh root@$_host screen -dm /path/to/recycle_process.sh
```

Now all you have to do is run `do_recycle.sh myhostname` from the command line of your master system, and (I believe) your problem will be solved. In this case, I don't think you'd need to keep a screen session alive. The process is just always running in the background. That said, I'm not exactly sure how you have things set up; you may have to alter the screen line in script 2 above to work with your environment.

Comment: Much if not all of this can also be accomplished with monit. If your needs include a "keepalive" function to protect against crashes, etc., you might take a look at it.